# Do we have quests in Witcher 3 with a time limit?

Tags: the-witcher-3

Sometimes a new quest starts with "I have to do that NOW" or "...immediately" or "...as soon as possible".

Are there any quests in Witcher 3 with a time limit?
Can I solve some quests only if I start it really "now" or "immediately" or within a specific time?

*(I don't ask for quests who starts at "midnight" or another specific time, it's about the available time until a quest fails)*

Answer (score 31, accepted):

No.

Even the quests that begin with "Meet me at the docks / tavern / Court of the (X) *immediately*" have no limit on starting / finishing, and will wait patiently for you to arrive (sometimes, admittedly, jibing you about hunting Drowners or similar when you arrive).

Quests (as you mention) that require you to meet folk/monsters at a given time of day will also loop indefinitely, day by day.

There are a few quests that will be failed if you continue with the main questline before completing them, but that's not related to timing.

Comment: Actually, this is not completely correct. I've encountered a mission where I've met a guy with this cart which was attacked by drowner. He told me some crap about being a merchant,in reality, he was carrying corpses. The merchant asked geralt to burn them, which gives you a few exp. I did that and died a few minutes later, where I forgot to burn the corpses again. While running through a random dungeon in order to get some griffon equipment, the quest failed. So i assume i had 24 hr to burn them. And because of that, i think there are (if only a few) quests in W3 which have a time limit.

Comment: Ooh, that's neat. Apologies - I'll change my answer.

Comment: @YUNOWORK Can you check the quest log for that quest? It should have a description on why the quest failed. Perhaps the NPC died or something similar (not related to time) happened? I remember reading someone starting (by accident) a "protect the NPC" type mission, and then continue doing his own thing. Obviously the NPC died without help and the quest failed. Still, it's hard to call it "time limited".

Comment: @Shaamaan Sure, once I'm at home, I'll take a look.

Comment: @Y U NO WORK: This is the only quest ever failed so far! In my case, the quest log says something (I play a german version, meaning translated) like: "Catch the merchant", "Knock him from the horse". Both parts are written in red. It was very early in the game and I didn't checked solved quests for completeness. In this case, it was not time related.

Comment: @PeterCo If you mean [Precious Cargo](http://www.ign.com/wikis/the-witcher-3-wild-hunt/Precious_Cargo), I failed the same one, and after only a minute or so from receiving the "knock him off" part (I didn't realize exactly what it wanted me to do). I don't know if it was based on time, distance, or location of the merchant, though.

Comment: @Geobits: Thanks! It seems, that I have missed this part: "He'll try to escape on horseback, prompting you to chase him down.

Summon Roach and ride hard to catch up, then go for a sword swipe when he's close enough." I just looted his cart...

Comment: Also there are some Items you find that require to Meet a person e.g. Triss, who is gone if you complet her questline bevor talking about that Item you found.

Comment: There are a few other small quests you can fail, or that vanish, if you don't do them right away. I remember 2: (1) 3 elfs confronting a human outside Novigrad, claiming he is a Fisstech dealer. If you see the exclamation mark on the map, but don't react to it, it will not come back. (2) in Novigrad, 2 merchants argue (a dwarf and a human), about a monster in a storehouse (a Nekker as it turns out). If you don't investigate right away, the quest fails. There are probably a few other quests with an exclamation mark with similar time limits.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add that it might be possible to fail "The Last Wish" if you do not immediately continue at least the starter task.  In my case, I was lured to start the Uma quest line and later saw "The Last Wish" ended up in my failed quests.

Honestly, Yen could have given further details.  A sorceress makes all matters "important to her", even trivial ones like brushing their hair.

I had not noticed until well into the Uma quest line so I will have to wait until NG+ to attempt that one again.

[image]